# Parent tag ID 1 is not among the open tags. FOR XML EXPLICIT requires parent tags to be opened first. Check the ordering of the result set

Tags: sql, xml

Hi all I try with the query below to write into file.
It's a dynamic call about 30 statement.
The first call is ok I write the line (result into variable and this one write in file). From the second round I got this error:
"Parent tag ID 1 is not among the open tags. FOR XML EXPLICIT requires parent tags to be opened first. Check the ordering of the result set".

I don't understood as I can resolve.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    1 as Tag,
    NULL as Parent,
    NULL AS [Products!1], -- empty root element
    NULL AS [Product!2!ExternalId!element],
    NULL AS [Product!2!Name!element],
    NULL AS [Product!2!Description!element],
    NULL AS [Product!2!BrandExternalId!element],
    NULL AS [Product!2!CategoryExternalId!element],
    NULL AS [Product!2!ProductPageUrl!cdata],
    NULL AS [Product!2!ImageUrl!cdata],
    NULL AS [Product!2!],
    NULL AS [Product!2!]
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    NULL,
    ExternalId,  
    [Name],
    [Description],
    REPLACE(BrandExternalId,'/','_') as BrandExternalId,
    IDnodo as CategoryExternalId,
    ProductPageUrl,
    ImageUrl,   
    (
    SELECT ManufacturerPartNumber
    FOR XML PATH('ManufacturerPartNumbers'),TYPE
    ),
    (SELECT b.EAN  
     FROM Cestino.acap.Bazaar_Servizio_01  b 
     WHERE (ff.ExternalId = b.codart)  
    AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', b.EAN) = 0
    AND CHARINDEX('.', b.EAN) = 0
     AND LEN(b.EAN) = 13
     AND isNumeric(b.EAN) = 1
     FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('EANs'), TYPE)
FROM Cestino.acap.Bazaar_Servizio_00  ff with (nolock) 
--WHERE ExternalId = 100212694
ORDER BY 3, Parent
OFFSET ((2 - 1) * 10000) ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

Comment: this is the page number...
OFFSET ((1 - 1) * 10000) ROWS
OFFSET ((2 - 1) * 10000) ROWS
OFFSET ((3 - 1) * 10000) ROWS
etc...

Comment: try    order by 3, tag, parent

Comment: NO always the same error... first row write... from the second always same error... ?MSSQLError HResult="0x80040e14" Source="Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Description="Parent tag ID 1 is not among the open tags. FOR XML EXPLICIT requires parent tags to be opened first. Check the ordering of the result set."?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    1 as Tag,
    NULL as Parent,
    NULL AS [Products!1], -- empty root element
    NULL AS [Product!2!ExternalId!element],
    NULL AS [Product!2!Name!element],
    NULL AS [Product!2!Description!element],
    NULL AS [Product!2!BrandExternalId!element],
    NULL AS [Product!2!CategoryExternalId!element],
    NULL AS [Product!2!ProductPageUrl!cdata],
    NULL AS [Product!2!ImageUrl!cdata],
    NULL AS [Product!2!],
    NULL AS [Product!2!]
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    NULL,
    ExternalId,  
    [Name],
    [Description],
    REPLACE(BrandExternalId,'/','_') as BrandExternalId,
    IDnodo as CategoryExternalId,
    ProductPageUrl,
    ImageUrl,   
    (
    SELECT ManufacturerPartNumber
    FOR XML PATH('ManufacturerPartNumbers'),TYPE
    ),
    (SELECT b.EAN  
     FROM Cestino.acap.Bazaar_Servizio_01  b 
     WHERE (ff.ExternalId = b.codart)  
    AND PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', b.EAN) = 0
    AND CHARINDEX('.', b.EAN) = 0
     AND LEN(b.EAN) = 13
     AND isNumeric(b.EAN) = 1
     FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('EANs'), TYPE)
FROM Cestino.acap.Bazaar_Servizio_00  ff with (nolock) 
--WHERE ExternalId = 100212694
ORDER BY 3, Parent
OFFSET ((2 - 1) * 10000) ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
Order by Tag
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Adding some information about what you did to solve the problem or how your code works will make your answer more useful.